# Foreach does not get xpath results from node

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, foreach, webdriver

I use xpath webdriver to find a div in the code and I need to get data on each node of this div, but this is not happening.

HTML:

```
<div class="elements">
    <div class="element"><div class="title">Title A</div></div>
    <div class="element"><div class="title">Title B</div></div>
    <div class="element"><div class="title">Title C</div></div>
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```
$elements = array();
$data = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath("//div[@class='elements']//div[@class='element']"));
foreach ($data as $i => $element) {
    $elements[$i]["title"] = $element->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath("//div[@class='title']"))->getText();
}
```

Result Array $elements being returned:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title A
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title A
        )

)
```

The above script is only returning Title A 3 times.
I need it to work like it has a numeral in xPath [x]. Exemple:

`(//div[@class='elements']//div[@class='element'])[1]//div[@class='title']` for Title A
`(//div[@class='elements']//div[@class='element'])[2]//div[@class='title']` for Title B
`(//div[@class='elements']//div[@class='element'])[3]//div[@class='title']` for Title C

I can't use numeral because xPath is too big and would mess up the code a lot.

Surely the correct node xPath in foreach wasn't supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `WebElement` to locate another `WebElement` with `xpath` you need to use current context `.` in the path

```
$element->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath(".//div[@class='title']"))
```